# Component do angular é renderizado várias em vez, porém só foi solicitado fazer isso uma vez

Tags: angular

Estou começando no angular e estou tendo um pequeno problema.
Estava seguindo um tutorial, e nele estava construindo uma applicação angular bem simples.
Nele temos basicamente 3 componentes, o app-root(principal) ,app-server e app-servers.

Nesse eu construi o html do  app-server , praticamente não fiz nada no .ts, ele tá praticamente no padrão de quando você cria um componente, só que olha só que estranho:

[[image: Imagem mostrando a renderização indevida]
<sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPDKw.png)

O meu app-server é renderizado infinitas vezes sendo que eu só referenciei ele uma vez no app-components.

Se alguém tiver dúvida como fiz segue meu código.

**Sever.component.html**:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>asd.</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

**server.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
            selector: 'app-server',
            templateUrl: './server.component.html'

})



export class ServerComponent {



}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<h3>I'm in the AppComponent</h3>


<hr>


<hr>
<app-servers></app-servers>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   name = 'lucas';
}
```

**app.modules.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**servers.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-servers',
  template: `<app-server></app-server><app-servers><app-server>`,
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})
export class ServersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer porque isso está acontecendo?? Aonde foi que eu errei? Eu revi o código alguma vezes e parece esta tudo certo.

Comment: porque tem uma tag html e body no seu componente?

Comment: porque, até onde eu sei,  é assim que docs html são estruturados. tag html  para indicar que inciou um doc html e body para configurar  os componentes  visiveis. Mas, Eu fiz um teste e tirei eles, parece que não é preciso usar esses tacs no angular, sem eles ele renderiza da mesma forma.

Comment: essa informações ficam no index.hmtl, no seu componente deixa somente o html referente a ele

Comment: eu dei uma debugada aqui, e achei o problema  ta em servers.component.ts: `template:<app-server></app-server><app-servers><app-server>`. Não sei pq , mais esse código ta gerando um loop infinito].

Comment: pq vc ta fazendo isso?

Comment: Não fiz isso propositalmente, provavelmete foi um erro de digitação. Eu tinha escrito esse código há algum tempo e voltei nele hoje pq voltei a fazer o curso, por isso tava muito confuso do pq tava acontecendo aquela parafernalha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você colocou `<app-servers>`, que é o selector do componente `ServersComponent`, dentro do seu próprio template.
Isso cria uma recursão infinita, pois toda vez que `app-servers` for renderizado, ele acaba criando uma nova instância dele mesmo, que em seguida criam mais outra instância e assim por diante.

O template correto neste caso seria esse:

```
template: `<app-server></app-server>`,
```

Esse template vai apenas imprimir o conteúdo do componente `ServerComponent` uma única vez.

Comment: excelente explicação faz todo  sentido. Agora eu entedi o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Eu não entendi muito bem o que você esta tentando fazer, mas tente trocar

template: `<app-server></app-server><app-servers><app-server>`

por

template: `<app-server></app-server><app-servers></app-server>`

ou

template: `<app-server></app-server>`

Comment: apenas estava seguindo um tutorial de um curso udemy, para começar no angular. Vc sabe explicar o pq estava acontecendo o loop?